# Exporting parent class React which includes child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I am changing my react app from ES5 syntax to ES6. I have stumbled across a problem with having two classes in one file and exporting the parent class.

When I add the class `Test` I get the following error:

> Parent.jsx:2Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./file.jsx"

My `file.jsx` file looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <Test />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       var welcome = 'Hello World!';
     }

    render() {
        return(
            <h1>{this.welcome}</h1>
        )
    }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable inside a class.
You can use a constructor method to set it if you want but your var welcome is causing troubles for the moment

Comment: thanks, i wasn't sure about that part also. So in a constructor is where I should set the variables? Ive updated the question

Comment: You're almost there. The only problem now is that your welcome var is scoped in the constructor function, and not added to the object. To correct this, simply do `this.welcome = "Hello world!";`

Comment: perfect, thanks! can you add that to the answer maybe?